# Matlab: delete elements of an Cell Array (Data Preparation)

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have a Cell Array D{7,x} with 7 rows and x columns (don't know it until now).

- In row 4 there are indexing numbers 1 and 2.
- In row 5 there are indexing letters A and B.
- In row 6 there are indices -1 and 1.
- In row 7 there are times.

Now I want to delete invalid Data from this array:

If there is a 1 in row 4; and A in row 5; and 1 in row 6 then the column should be deleted.

Same principle for combination of 1, B, -1 and 2, A, -1 and 2, B, 1 (always when this triple appears together in one column)

and in row 7: if the value is < 0.2 or > 2 (also whole column invalid).

What would be the best way to do this?
I thought of a for loop over the length of D, but I don't know how to delete the column where the combination appears and at all I have no idea how to do it efficient.

Would be really grateful for your ideas!

Comment: It is always a good idea to show what you have tried so far, i.e. include your for loop method, and to avoid asking multiple questions at once, i.e. efficient implementation and deleting columns. It will make much better reusable questions & answers.

Answer (score 1):

*for* loop is a solution. The caution, when you use *for* loop to remove content, is to loop starting from the end. I am using your first criterion as an example in this answer:

```
for i = size(D,2):-1:1
    if D{4,i}==1 && strcmp(D{5,i}, 'A') && D{6,i}==1 % use {}
        D(:,i) = [];
    end
end
```

To avoid *for* loop, you may need *cell2mat*, or [D{4,:}], for numeric columns:

```
ind = [D{4,:}]==1 & strcmp(D(5,:), 'A') & [D{6,:}]==1; % or
% ind = cell2mat(D(4,:))==1 & strcmp(D(5,:), 'A') & cell2mat(D(6,:))==1;
D(:, ind) = [];
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! This  seems to work, I think. Is this always the case, that I have to start a loop at the end when I delete something?
So now I could either add the other if statements in the loop or create 4 or 5 separate ind variables, right? For the last condition this would be something like this: 
ind4 = [D{7,:}]< 0.2 | [D{7,:}]> 2;
D(:, ind4) = [];   
??

Comment: @LotteLi You got it! To delete from end is a simple solution. If you loop from beginning, you will need to create indices to be deleted, and delete them once outside the loop.